# Aligning images - horizontally

Tags: css, image, alignment

If you go to my site: www.ryancoughlin.com - and if you see the Google, Yahoo, etc. RSS buttons on the right side of the page. I am trying to get them to align evenly, they are all the same image height and I have been trying to get them to evenly line up. But I have had no success.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Seems you are missing `class="feed-image"` on the Yahoo image.

Comment: dammit.  you beat me by like 8 seconds.

Comment: Thank you! That is bad on my part....sorry for that. I should have picked that up.

Thank you everyone for your help.

Ryan

Answer (score 1):

Try to specify them as "inline" instead of block, this should allow you to treat them as words. 
Another chance is to make a list (this seems appropriate since the nature of that "list" of images) and let the "li" elements float left (then adjust margins).

Also I think you should change your title in "Aligning images - vertically" to ease future users' search.